# Certain text is being displayed multiple times in a row and certain promps aren't appearing at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, loops

I'm making a "Texas Hold 'em" game, and what keeps happening is the output is:

```
Player 1's hand:
  Queen of Spades
  10 of Hearts

Player 2's hand:
  ???  ???

Community cards:
  Jack of Clubs
  Ace of Clubs
  7 of Clubs

Pot: 40
Player 1, enter your bet amount (current balance: 980): 100 

Player 1's hand:
  Queen of Spades
  10 of Hearts

Player 2's hand:
  ???  ???

Community cards:
  Jack of Clubs
  Ace of Clubs
  7 of Clubs

Pot: 160

Player 1's hand:
  Queen of Spades
  10 of Hearts

Player 2's hand:
  ???  ???

Community cards:
  Jack of Clubs
  Ace of Clubs
  7 of Clubs
  2 of Spades

Pot: 160
Player 1, enter your bet amount (current balance: 880): 100

Player 1's hand:
  Queen of Spades
  10 of Hearts

Player 2's hand:
  ???  ???

Community cards:
  Jack of Clubs
  Ace of Clubs
  7 of Clubs
  2 of Spades

Pot: 280

Player 1's hand:
  Queen of Spades
  10 of Hearts

Player 2's hand:
  ???  ???

Community cards:
  Jack of Clubs
  Ace of Clubs
  7 of Clubs
  2 of Spades
  3 of Clubs

Pot: 280
Player 1, enter your bet amount (current balance: 780): 100

Player 1's hand:
  ???  ???

Player 2's hand:
  Queen of Hearts
  3 of Spades

Community cards:
  Jack of Clubs
  Ace of Clubs
  7 of Clubs
  2 of Spades
  3 of Clubs

Pot: 400
Winner: Player 2
```

The output should resemble the one below, however you can see the top one is repeating text and not asking for an input between rounds 2 and 3.

```
Player one's hand: (insert hand)
Player 2s hand: ?????

Community cards:
a
b
c

pot: (insert pot)
player 1: how much to bet?

Player one's hand: (insert hand)
Player 2s hand: ?????

Community cards:
a
b
c
d

pot: (insert pot)
player 1: how much to bet?

Player one's hand: (insert hand)
Player 2s hand: ?????

Community cards:
a
b
c
d
e

pot: (insert pot)
player 1: how much to bet?

winner: xyz
player 2s cards were: (insert player 2s (the bots) cards)
```

I tried switching from loops to a straight forward turn by turn approach. However it isn't working and it's still displaying things at the wrong time. The actual code is below:

```
import random

# Initialize deck and shuffle
suits = ['Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Spades']
values = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']
deck = [{'suit': suit, 'value': value} for suit in suits for value in values]
random.shuffle(deck)

# Initialize players
players = [{'name': f'Player {i + 1}', 'hand': [], 'chips': 1000, 'money': 1000} for i in range(2)]
pot = 0  # Current pot value
community_cards = []

# Deal a hand of cards
def deal_hand(num_cards=2):
    return [deck.pop() for _ in range(num_cards)]

# Deal a specified number of community cards
def deal_community_cards(num_cards):
    return [deck.pop() for _ in range(num_cards)]

# Display the community cards
def display_community(community_cards):
    print("\nCommunity cards:")
    if community_cards:
        for card in community_cards:
            print(f"  {card['value']} of {card['suit']}")
    else:
        print("  No community cards yet.")

# Determine the winner(s) of the game
def determine_winner(players, community_cards):
    for player in players:
        player['best_hand'] = evaluate_hand(player['hand'], community_cards)

    best_hand_value = max(player['best_hand'][0] for player in players)
    winners = [player for player in players if player['best_hand'][0] == best_hand_value]

    if len(winners) > 1:
        for i in range(5):
            max_kicker_value = max(player['best_hand'][1][i] for player in winners)
            winners = [player for player in winners if player['best_hand'][1][i] == max_kicker_value]
            if len(winners) == 1:
                break
            elif len(winners) == 0:
                raise ValueError("No valid winners")
    return winners

# Evaluate a player's hand
def evaluate_hand(player_hand, community_cards):
    all_cards = player_hand + community_cards
    values = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13, 'Ace': 14}
    suits = set(card['suit'] for card in all_cards)
    values_count = {value: sum(1 for card in all_cards if card['value'] == value) for value in values}
    sorted_values = sorted(values_count.keys(), key=lambda x: (values_count[x], values[x]), reverse=True)

    if len(suits) == 1:
        flush = True
    else:
        flush = False

    straight = False
    if len(sorted_values) >= 5:
        straight_values = sorted_values[:5]
        straight_values_int = [values[value] for value in straight_values]
    if straight_values_int[-1] - straight_values_int[0] == 4:
        straight = True
    elif values[straight_values[-1]] == 14 and values[straight_values[0]] == 2 and values[straight_values[1]] == 3 and values[straight_values[2]] == 4 and values[straight_values[3]] == 5:
        straight = True
        straight_values_int = [2, 3, 4, 5, 14]
    if straight and flush:
        return (9, straight_values)

    if 4 in values_count.values():
        value = next(key for key, value in values_count.items() if value == 4)
        return (8, [value] * 4 + [v for v in sorted_values if v != value][:1])

    if 3 in values_count.values() and 2 in values_count.values():
        three_value = next(key for key, value in values_count.items() if value == 3)
        two_value = next(key for key, value in values_count.items() if value == 2)
        return (7, [three_value] * 3 + [two_value] * 2)

    if flush:
        return (6, sorted_values)

    if straight:
        return (5, straight_values)

    if 3 in values_count.values():
        value = next(key for key, value in values_count.items() if value == 3)
        return (4, [value] * 3 + [v for v in sorted_values if v != value][:2])

    if list(values_count.values()).count(2) == 2:
        pairs = [key for key, value in values_count.items() if value == 2]
        return (3, pairs + [v for v in sorted_values if v not in pairs][:1])

    if 2 in values_count.values():
        pair_value = next(key for key, value in values_count.items() if value == 2)
        return (2, [pair_value] * 2 + [v for v in sorted_values if v != pair_value][:3])

    return (1, sorted_values[:5])

# Display the current state of the game
def display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot, reveal_player=0, game_over=False):
    for i, player in enumerate(players):
        if i == reveal_player or game_over:
            print(f"\n{player['name']}'s hand:")
            for card in player['hand']:
                print(f"  {card['value']} of {card['suit']}")
        else:
            print(f"\n{player['name']}'s hand:")
            print("  ???  ???")

    display_community(community_cards)
    print(f"\nPot: {pot}")

# Simulate a single turn of the game
def play_turn():
    global pot, deck
    for player in players:
        player['hand'] = deal_hand()
        player['money'] -= 20
        pot += 20

    # First round
    community_cards.extend(deal_community_cards(3))
    display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot)

    # Betting for player 1
    bet_amount_1 = input(f"{players[0]['name']}, enter your bet amount (current balance: {players[0]['money']}): ")
    bet_amount_1 = int(bet_amount_1)
    players[0]['money'] -= bet_amount_1
    pot += bet_amount_1

    # Betting for player 2
    player_2_bet = 20
    players[1]['money'] -= player_2_bet
    pot += player_2_bet

    # Display state after bets
    display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot)

    # Second round
    community_cards.extend(deal_community_cards(1))
    display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot)

    # Betting for player 1
    bet_amount_2 = input(f"{players[0]['name']}, enter your bet amount (current balance: {players[0]['money']}): ")
    bet_amount_2 = int(bet_amount_2)
    players[0]['money'] -= bet_amount_2
    pot += bet_amount_2

    # Betting for player 2
    player_2_bet = 20
    players[1]['money'] -= player_2_bet
    pot += player_2_bet

    # Display state after bets
    display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot)

    # Third round
    community_cards.extend(deal_community_cards(1))
    display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot)

    # Betting for player 1
    bet_amount_3 = input(f"{players[0]['name']}, enter your bet amount (current balance: {players[0]['money']}): ")
    bet_amount_3 = int(bet_amount_3)
    players[0]['money'] -= bet_amount_3
    pot += bet_amount_3

    # Betting for player 2
    player_2_bet = 20
    players[1]['money'] -= player_2_bet
    pot += player_2_bet

    # Display final state
    display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot, reveal_player=1)

    # Determine winner
    winners = determine_winner(players, community_cards)
    if len(winners) == 1:
        print(f"Winner: {winners[0]['name']}")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!")

# Run a single turn of the game
play_turn()
```

Comment: You're calling `display_game_state(players, community_cards, pot)` before the first bet, and then you call it again after the bet but before the next card has been dealt.  So of course it displays the same community cards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is working as expected, you just have a few additional `display_game_state()` calls, which cause the repeating text.

Try removing the `display_game_state` on lines `141` `159` and `177` (below 'Display state after bets' and 'Display final state')

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/jovial-cache-xsr6sz?file=%2Fmain.py) is a sandbox to the amended code with example input. The output seems to match your expected output now